# Expo iOS project built with Xcode launches Expo Go environment and not my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have a bare Expo workflow so I have access to the iOS folder. When I open the workspace in Xcode and build the app, the app that runs is not my project but what you would see in expo go instead (i.e. asking you to visit the development server)

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Some context:

- Cannot use EAS build at the moment so our org is unable to provide a distribution certificate
- I do have an apple developer account
- The app runs properly on the simulator